# How to preserve last_insert_id() of mysql in jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, mysql-workbench, jsp-tags

Here is my sql code. I wanted to execute this queries through jsp:

```
insert into student(student_name) values('sachin');
select last_insert_id();
set @a=last_insert_id();

insert into course(credits,course_name) values ('3','capstone');
select last_insert_id();
set @b=last_insert_id();

insert into faculty(faculty_name) values('bernard');
select last_insert_id();
set @c=last_insert_id();

insert into class(faculty_id,course_id,semester,day,time) values(@c,@b,'spring 2015','Friday','5.30pm');
select last_insert_id();
set @g=last_insert_id();

insert into grades(student_id,class_id,grade) values (@a,@g,'C');

insert into attendance(student_id,class_id,classes_attended,classes_missed) 
values (@a,@g,'25','5');
```

I tried to preserve the auto-incremented value of the table using this query `set @a=last_insert_id();` in `jsp` but this is not working. I think this is not a right statement to preserve a value into a variable in jsp. Can anyone please tell me how to preserve the auto-incremented value in jsp? I'm trying to use the preserved value for another table. I got struck to here many days ago. Anyone help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After the code you have shown, do

```
 select @a AS last_student_id, @g AS last_class_id
```

This will return a one-row two-column result set to your program with the values of those two numbers.